# Reference request about some topics of numerical analysis

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

Can anyone give me some nice references for the following topics at **graduate** level:

1) Iterative methods for linear systems: Jacobi Method, Gauss-Seidel Method, conjugate gradient method;

2) Linear and non-linear least squares;

3) Numerical integration: Newton Cotes, Romberg integration, gaussian quadrature, error analysis;

4) Numerical Methods for ordinary differential equations: Finite differences, Taylor, Runge-Kutta;

I'm looking for something very rigorous.

Thanks

Comment: Check Numerical Analysis: A Mathematical Introduction 1st Edition
by Michelle Schatzman. Absolutely wonderful book.

Comment: I like Rainer Kress's Numerical Analysis for that purpose. Everything is built on functional analysis, so it's about as rigorous as you need.

Comment: I also like "Theoretical Numerical Analysis" by Kendall Atkinson, but I don't like it quite as much as Kress.